# Vertical line table

Tags: tables, line

I would like to have a vertical line before the last column, despite I used this symbol "vertical line" it does not appear, why?

```
  \begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
%  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.14cm} % Abstand zwischen den Spalten einer Tabelle
  \caption{babalaba.}
   \begin{tabular}{ccclc}
\toprule
 {L1}&{Linkers}&{L3}&{Dyes} \\
   \hline 
    RNA1 & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.72ex]{cL}& {D dye}\\
   \\[-1em]
 blabla & & {D dye}\\
%\bottomrule
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\label{table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUukj.png]

Indeed I used the letter l instead of |

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.14cm} % Abstand zwischen den Spalten einer 
Tabelle
  \caption{babalaba.}
\begin{tabular}{ccc|c}
\toprule
{L1}&{Linkers}&{L3}&{Dyes} \\
\hline 
 RNA1 & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.72ex]{cL}&{D dye}\\
 \\[-1em]
 blabla & & {D dye}\\
%\bottomrule
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\label{table1}
\end{table}
 \end{document}
```

However now I have a discontinuous vertical line:[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: It seems you wrote `l` (L-letter) instead of `|` in the tabular definition.

Comment: You should only add the required packages to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \makegapedcells
  \centering
\caption{babalaba.}
\begin{tabular}{ccc|c}
    \toprule
{L1} & {Linkers} & {L3} & {Dyes}            \\
    \midrule
 RNA1 & \multirow{2}{*}[-3pt]{cL}&{D dye}   \\
 blabla & & {D dye}                         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

use of `booktabs`' rules and vertical lines gives quite ugly result: discontinuous vertical lines. to remove them, you can set vertical distances above(below rues and this distance replaces with facility of some other packages, for example by `makecell` as is done in above mwe.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
%  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.14cm} % Abstand zwischen den Spalten einer 
Tabelle
\caption{babalaba.}
\begin{tabular}{ccc!{\vrule width 0.2em}c}
    \specialrule{0.2em}{0em}{0em}
{L1}&{Linkers}&{L3}&{Dyes} \\
    \specialrule{0.2em}{0em}{0em}
 RNA1 & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.72ex]{cL}&{D dye}\\
 blabla & & {D dye}\\
    \specialrule{0.2em}{0em}{0em}
\end{tabular}
\label{table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the lines are too tight.